# Excel: Unique Values with Multiplier

Tags: excel

I have an Excel Table with two Columns Users and Genres

```
Users   Genre               
1   Action              
3   Action  Mystery Thriller        
1   Action  Adventure   Drama       
1   Action  Adventure   Fantasy
```

I would like to get all the number of users who are in each genre
If there is more than one user assigned to a genre then the number of users should be multiplied

So for example

Action should have 1 + 3 + 1 + 1 = 6

Mystery should have 3

Thriller should have 3

Adventure should have 1 + 1 = 2

Drama should have 1

Fantasy should have 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" " & F1 & " "," " & $B$1:$B$7 & " ")),$A$1:$A$7))
```

where `$A$1:$A$10` is your users range and `$B$1:$B$10` genre range.

Note, since it's an array formula, you should press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it.

Here is [test workbook](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g34hg9cq0ab5qn9/simoco_.xlsx) with step by step tutorial how to apply this formula (see @Stephenmelb answer for details).

Comment: How can I do it without hardcoding the find "adventure".  There is a way for Excel to create a table with all the unique values and their counts eg. using a pivot table?

Comment: Also the Genre column is actually split across many different columns as the space is a delimiter

Comment: `Also the Genre column is actually split across many different columns as the space is a delimiter` - in that case I don't think you could use pivot table. You should split your text in columns before..

Comment: I have already split the genre column into many columns using the text to columns feature.  I am not sure what to do now?

Comment: I'm not sure I can help you to do it in pivot table

Comment: Is there any other way to do with then?  I don't want to hard code the genre, I would like Excel to generate all the unique genres.

Comment: So, now you have one column with users, and a few columns with generes. Do you open to VBA?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47225/discussion-between-simoco-and-stephenmelb)

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way by simoco

suppose that your data in columns A and B. Copy column B to, say column F, next step make "text to columns" for column F. Next step you would get few splitted columns with genre: F, G, H,.... Copy all content of G,H,.. to the bottom of column F. Then use "Remove duplicate" for column F. In that moment you would have unique values in column F. ANd finally use this formula in example in G1: =SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(F1,$B$1:$B$10)),$A$1:$A$10)) and drag it down