# Excel: Find function

Tags: excel

I have a Table with a Columns Genre Users

```
Genre               Users
Science               3
Science Fiction       4
```

I would like to find the sum of Science Users and Science Fiction Users.

When I do a FIND() lookup for "Science", it'll add all the Science Fiction users to the Science Users because the strings match,

I have tried to change Science Fiction to Science_Fiction but FIND() still thinks Science_Fiction is part of Science.

**This question is related to** [**another question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697378/excel-unique-values-with-multiplier/)

Comment: try this: `=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" " & F1 & " "," " & $B$1:$B$7 & " ")),$A$1:$A$7))` ? But before change `Science Fiction` to `Science_Fiction`

Comment: see my upd answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697378/excel-unique-values-with-multiplier/21697458#21697458)

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A10="Science")+(A2:A10="Science Fiction");B2:B10)
```

names in A2:A10, users in B2:B10